# Is there a typesafe enum conversion from int in c#?

Tags: c#, casting, enums, compiler-errors

I know that I can convert an int to an enum using a cast

```
MyEnumType myEnum = (MyEnumType) myInteger;
```

The problem here is that the runtime cast won't stop me at build time if myInteger is not of type `int`

```
void MyMethod(MyObject myObject)
{
    MyEnumType myEnum = (MyEnumType) myObject.someProperty;
    ....
}
```

The above is not an uncommon code pattern but it won't protect me at build-time if the object's property type has been changed.

Is there a built-in method to do this conversion that will give me a build-time error? I could, of course, write a generic method rather easily but I'm wondering if one is built in.

Comment: Even if that were possible, how could you expect to get a build-time error when performing a cast of a value that is only known at run-time?  What other "non-int" types are you expecting to convert from? You cannot cast any arbitrary object to an enum.

Comment: @JeffMercado my hope is **not** to perform the cast. A typed method would give me compile-time feedback since I am not relying on a cast.

Comment: i think "Enum.TryParse(myInteger.ToString())" should work. (HD repairing, no way to test here).

Comment: Give an example of a non-int type for `someProperty` that compiles?

Comment: @MarvinSmit you may be correct according to MSDN. I have only used TryParse for string representations before, never ints, but it seems ints will work... convert your comment to an answer

Comment: @Matthew if `someProperty` isn't of type `int` then you wouldn't *want* the code to compile in a statically typed world because it's possible for a non-int value to be in that expression.  The only way to write a method to which compiling means it will be successfully run is for the compile time type of that expression to be `int`.

Comment: @Servy yes, that's precisely my point. I don't want my code to compile. But if `someProperty` is of type `object` then it *will* compile.

Comment: @Matthew Okay, just making sure I understood your meaning properly.

Comment: @Matthew Of course it will compile for type object.  The object could contain a boxed value of your enum type and your cast would allow that value to be unboxed.  The compiler can't know what's in the object, so it can't prove that the cast will always fail.

Comment: @Kyle so my point is that I want strongly type the conversion to `int`

Comment: Given than an enum can be any integral type (byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong), it wouldn't be possible to check for overflow at compile time, so why would it help to check the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Enum.TryParse(myInteger.ToString(), out result)
```

to get the Enum value of an int.

Hope this helps,

Comment: That's not how you call `TryParse`.  Additionally, it's for taking a string that represents the name of one of the enum's values, not the integer representation, so this wouldn't work even if you fixed how you call it.

Comment: @Servy according to MSDN you can call `TryParse` using the integer value, too. I didn't know that, either. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: According to the MSDN docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx it does take the name OR underlying value

Comment: In any case, this doesn't apply static typing at all.  The goal is to ensure that you can only compile the code when you know the conversion will succeed, so that if the programmer calls the method on something of the wrong type they get a compile time error, rather than a bug at runtime.  This method doesn't do that.  You can call `ToString` on anything.  This is no better than casting.

Comment: It may not throw a compile time error, but it will also not throw a runtime error....

Comment: @Matthew Which is still not what the question asks for.  In fact, not throwing at runtime would be *worse*.  You now not only have a bug, but you don't *know* that you have a bug.  It will result in unexpected behavior in which the problems are created much further away from where the problematic code is.  If you *do* make this mistake you *want* it to throw an exception.  Of course, the whole point of the question is to get code that, when it compiles, it will always work, not matter what.  This doesn't do that.

Comment: @Servy you're right, but the explicit `TryParse` call encourages me to handle the fail case in code. If it doesn't parse then I must do something else. The benefit is that TryParse will force me to use an `int` actually defined by my enum whereas a cast will let me use any int.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method to do this for your one enum easily enough:

```
public static MyEnumType CastFromInt<T>(int n)
{
    return (MyEnumType)n;
}
```

Sadly, because there is no way to apply a generic constraint such that a generic type argument is an enumeration, there's no *good* way to genericize this.  You could write something like this:

```
public static T CastFromInt<T>(int n)
{
    return (T)(object)n;
}
```

but that assumes the caller uses an enum as the type of `T`.  If they don't, it has problems.  This also needlessly boxes the integer.

Comment: The OP asked for a "build-time error".  This will not fail at compile time.  This will actually hide errors that otherwise would have occurred at compile time such as `MyEnumType = 3`.  What the OP wants to do simply is not possible.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey The first one is exactly what the OP is looking for, it just needs to be written for each type of enum.  The second will *only* fail at runtime if a non-enum value is used for `T`, or an enum that's not backed by an integer is used for `T`.  In the case of the first method there is no call to the method that will compile and not successfully convert the integer to the given enumeration.

Comment: `MyEnumType e = 3` => Compile time error if this value is not valid.  `MyEnumType e = CastFromInt<MyEnumType>(3)` => Runtime error.  Downgrade.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey That second snippet *won't* throw an error at runtime.  It will return an instance of that enumeration representing the value `3`.  If the enum is backed by an int anyway.  What makes you think that'll fail?  For the record, `MyEnumType e = 3` *always* fails to compile, there is no "if there isn't a valid value".  It will never compile, ever.

Comment: Oh nm, sorry I screwed up something in my test.

Comment: @Servy where would you recommend I place the methods?

Comment: @Matthew In a class declared in the same location as the enumeration, or wherever is most convenient otherwise.  If you use the second one then you'd want to do something to make it clear that it should be used only with enums, i.e. something like `EnumOperations` so that people don't try to use it to cast an int to a `double` or something.